# What are the steps for a Extrasolar system human colony?

Tags: society, planets, science-fiction, space-colonization

what would be the steps and conditions required to enstablish a new human colony on another world out of our system?

Shoudl it be a moon or a planet ? What conditions should have ? where to be located ? 
What would be the first steps to colonize , what needed? 
What would be the steps to convert it from an outpost to a self endependant colony ? 
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Please limit yourself to asking one question per post.

Comment: Hello Naima. Your question is much too broad because all of your questions  (you should only have one question per post) must be answered with "It depends". You need to specify what your colonists want. Who is trying to establish the colony? Who will actually be going there: settlers, workers; scientists; prisoners? What do they have to work with, is there a free choice of planets/planetoids or are they limited? Where in the galaxy are the settling? Do they need to be close to Sol or is that not a requirement? And so on...

Comment: When you put "science-based" on a question such as this it is as if you ask: "Can you specify how fast — accurate down to the second please — how fast a glass of milk will go bad?", without specifying any conditions about and around that glass of milk. It puts an impossible strain on those that are supposed to answer.

Comment: Ok sorry  , my question is generic because I didn't thought about adding more input in that. The colony is formed by willing settlers , Its unimportant who makes it but I just would like to know what would be the scientific steps and requirements for the possible success of it . Like position in the CHZ, the presence of particular planetary conditions, if must be a planet or a moon or else, eventually wich would be the steps for making it develope from an outpost to a colony , what is required to make it selfsufficent etc.

Comment: Steps and requirements would *not* be scientific. Why did Americans land in the moon? Requirements are economical and **political**.

Comment: Oh, and please, do not provide extra details in comments only. Everything important should go directly into your question. You can edit any time you want, only edits that invalidate existing answers are discouraged — but there are no answers yet.

Comment: OK, your question is on hold now. That's **nothing bad**. People can't answer it, so you can **edit it** to make it less broad, to provide context like tech level and political situation. Basically see comments and edit your question in a way that addresses most of the issues pointed there. After edit, it will appear that the reopen queue.

Comment: Ok I removed science based ok?

Comment: @Naima no, still too broad. Can you focus either on _steps_ or _conditions_ in your question (or ask 2 separate questions)?

Comment: I dunno how to do or what to remove ... may be what would nasa do to colonize an extrasolar system provided had infinite money and support and technology ?